# How do you Create this Terrain?

Tags: modeling

I have seen this Terrain in a video and i have tried to recreate it but i failed.
So my question is How do i create this Terrain ?

Source: [YouTube Video](https://youtu.be/nU6PF8vuEBk?t=65) [Starts at 01:05]

Pictures:

[image: Picture 1]
[image: Picture 2]
[image: Picture 3]
[image: Picture 4]

Thanks for all Answers

Comment: Hi. It's not clear to me how best to help you because we don't know what task you're exactly struggling with at the moment, nor what exactly you've already tried that failed. Would you be willing to edit the question to make it more focused?

Comment: I want to make this Terrain that is a little bit Low poly and reflects light i hope that makes it clear enough.